# How to make a specific slideshow?

Tags: javascript, html

does anyone know how do I make an image slideshow? tried searching it in the internet, didn't find anything helpful..
I need slideshow like in this page : http://www.hapoelb7.co.il/Team.asp
p.s. sorry for my bad english....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See  [owlcarousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/animate.html) might solve your problem

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It is a nice site but I need the slideshow with the arrows in the sides, so if you know how to do that, it will be very helpful.

Comment: If you see the examples and documentation's of this plugin you will find how to do that

Comment: http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/basic.html see here

Comment: And all example here http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/demos.html

Comment: OK thank you very much man

Comment: can you please accept this answer as helpful or vote up?

Comment: I accept this as helpful I can't vote up....